# How to add image to REST docs api documentation

Tags: gradle, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I'm using Spring Rest Docs to generate the API documentation for my APIs.

Now I want to add an image to this documentation. I know how to link the image in the asciidoctor file, and in IntelliJ Idea the preview shows the image, but when I generate the API documentation using Rest Docs and Gradle, the image is not shown.

What do I need to do in order to get the image in the generated API documentation?

Comment: It should just work as standard Asciidoctor works when including an image in some documentation. Can you share an example that illustrates what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually rather simple to get this done. Thanks to the remark by Andy Wilkinson I dug back into the documentation.

I used a folder called 'resources' relative to the .adoc file instead of naming that folder 'images', after renaming it to 'images' my images show up.